# Adding NSMutableAttributedString into a TextField

Tags: ios, uitextfield, nsattributedstring

I have a custom UITextfield which I want when the user finishes typing, a small "R$" must be added at the begging of the text with different size.

I call the method to add the "R$" like this:

```
self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(setCurrencyLabelPosition), for: .editingDidEnd)
```

and then I try to change the attributes and content like this:

```
 func setCurrencyLabelPosition(){

        let fullText:String = "R$\((self.text)!)"
        self.text = fullText
        var attribute:NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString:self.attributedText!)
        attribute.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value:UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12), range: NSRange(location:  0, length: 2))
        self.attributedText = attribute

    }
```

the original text of this textfield is set for size 40.0, I want only the "R$" to be of size 12.0

The problem I'm facing is that the whole text gets the size 40.0
It prints the "R$" but the size of 40.

Is it possible to do what I'm trying to using NSMutableAttributedString?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had been working on your question, I think there is a bug in `UITextField` because if you modify the font to bigger font it works but if you do so but for small font then don't work.

I have done a custom class and added some customizable Inspectable properties, hope this finally help you

This is  how looks, ***Note: the glitch is because of my gif converter***
[image]

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class CustomTextField: UITextField {

    @IBInspectable var prefix : String = ""
    @IBInspectable var removePrefixOnEditing : Bool = true

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(setCurrencyLabelPosition), for: .editingDidEnd)
        self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(removePrefix), for: .editingDidBegin)
    }

    func removePrefix(){
        if self.attributedText != nil
        {
            if(self.removePrefixOnEditing)
            {
                self.defaultTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)]
                let prefixRange = NSString(string: (self.attributedText?.string)!).range(of: prefix)
                if(prefixRange.location != NSNotFound)
                {
                    self.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: (self.attributedText?.string.replacingOccurrences(of: prefix, with: ""))!, attributes: self.defaultTextAttributes)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func setCurrencyLabelPosition(){

        if self.attributedText != nil
        {
            var fullText:String = "\((self.attributedText?.string)!)"
            if(NSString(string: (self.attributedText?.string)!).range(of: prefix).location == NSNotFound)
            {
                fullText = "\(prefix)\((self.attributedText?.string)!)"
            }
            //hacky part, seems to be a bug in UITextField
            self.defaultTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10)]
            self.attributedText = NSAttributedString(attributedString: self.changeFontForText(originalText: fullText, text: prefix, basicFont: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20), newFont: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)))
        }
    }

    func changeFontForText(originalText:String,text:String,basicFont:UIFont, newFont:UIFont) -> NSMutableAttributedString
    {
        let resultAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: originalText, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName : basicFont])
        let range = NSString(string: originalText).range(of: text)
        if(range.location != NSNotFound)
        {
            resultAttributedString.setAttributes([NSFontAttributeName:newFont], range: range)
        }

        return resultAttributedString
    }

}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It's weird because if I use             resultAttributedString.addAttribute(NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName, value: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue, range: range)
 it works... but changing the font doesn't work

Comment: Instead of using system font I tried Zapfino font... and the whole text changed to Zapfino... omg wtf is going on here???

Comment: @FredericoNovackAmaralPereir check my answer again was edited the Use it part, hope finally help you

Comment: I'm wondering if the issue lies because it does `setAttributedText:` but afterwards for some reason it does `setText:`, and use then the `.font` property of the `UITextField` which use the font of size 40.

Comment: @FredericoNovackAmaralPereir did you try my updated answer?

Comment: Sorry @ReinierMelian still not working... "R$" still appears with size 40

Comment: @FredericoNovackAmaralPereir I will review and adjust my code, and post my results

Comment: Ok I'll be waiting and later today I'll do some more tests

Comment: @ReinierMelian keep in mind that with your solution I can change the color, underline it, bold the text but never change it's size

Comment: @FredericoNovackAmaralPereir seems to have a bug there, my answer was edited please let me know if fixes your problem, for me works just fine

Comment: @FredericoNovackAmaralPereir Iam glad that helps you, best regards!